# What's up with the Fontmatrix project?

Tags: fonts

I'm quite fond of Fontmatrix, but it seems to be "dead" - at least the site of the project is down. Does anyone have information about that, or a possible fork that I should start to use etc.?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.fontmatrix.be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, what happened is that Pierre had to take other responsibilities, and since he was pretty much the only person who wrote code, the work on the project stopped.

It looks like I'm the only Fontmatrix team member left, so I took responsibility to move the development to Github:

https://github.com/fontmatrix/fontmatrix

There's not much happening right now, as I have very little development skills. We'll see what happens next.

There are still some things to do before a new release can happen: finalizing the UI update, fixing opentype shaping bugs etc.

Comment: hey Alexandre :), do you still work on fontmatrix currently?

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://www.ohloh.net/p/fontmatrix for a quick overview of how development is proceeding. Looks like it is still moving but has slowed down in the last couple of years. Perhaps that's just because it's got a fairly simple aim, and development is more or less "finished"?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it was once a fully-functional piece of software, and now the repos for newer versions of Ubuntu (and Mint, and similar distros) is unfinished and barely functional.

Here's how to get the 'full' version of FontMatrix: first [go here and get libicu44](http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-11.10/ubuntu-main-i386/libicu44_4.4.2-2_i386.deb/download/). Then [get fontmatrix_0.6.0+svn20100107-2ubuntu4_i386.deb](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/fontmatrix/). Now you will have the old, fully-functional version.

Answer (score 0):

[Fontmatrix](http://packages.ubuntu.com/Fontmatrix) [image: Install Fontmatrix]
 is a font manager built with the kind of features and abilities graphic designers, layout pros, and others have felt necessary, but modernized with some new touches.

It is in the ubuntu repro you can search fontmatrix in ubuntu software center.

Fontmatrix Launchpad [page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fontmatrix)

Fontmatrix available in all kind of [ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=fontmatri&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)

Comment: ... interesting background ... but the OP question is what has happened to the project itself.

Comment: with respect to the website is down does not mean that the development is abandoned... the ubuntu repro has the latest version of this program..